# Summarise with row-based filter for multiple operations

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `df` that should be used to compute some ratios (divisions) following `a group_by` for multiple entries abased on the entries of a single column (`cond3`):

```
cond1 cond2 cond3 value
foo   oof   A     1
foo   oof   B     2
foo   oof   D     3
foo   bar   A     1
foo   bar   B     2
foo   bar   C     4
foo   bar   D     4
buz   oof   A     2
buz   oof   C     1
buz   oof   B     3
bar   rab   C     3
bar   rab   B     4  
bar   rab   D     2
```

I can accomplish this this for a single selection and dividing by another as follows:

```
df %>% group_by(cond1, cond2) %>% 
  summarise(ratio = value[cond3 == "A"] / value[cond3 == "B"])
```

Now, lets assume I have two lists like:

```
list1 <- c("A","C")
list2 <- c("B","D")
```

and I want to perform the division for multiple combinations.
This can be done explicitly like this:

```
    df %>% group_by(cond1, cond2) %>% 
      summarise(ratio_AB = value[cond3 == "A"] / value[cond3 == "B"],
ratio_AD = value[cond3 == "A"] / value[cond3 == "D"],
ratio_CB = value[cond3 == "C"] / value[cond3 == "B"],
ratio_CD = value[cond3 == "C"] / value[cond3 == "D"])
```

I would like to have this implicitly done like a pseudo-loop:

```
df %>% group_by(cond1, cond2) %>% 
  summarise(ratios = value[cond3 %in% list1] / value[cond3 %in% list2])
```

The expected output without the average:

```
   cond1 cond2 ratio_AB ratio_AD ratio_CB ratio_CD
 1 foo   oof   0.5      0.67     NA       NA 
 2 foo   bar   0.5      0.25     2        1
 3 buz   oof   0.67     NA       0.67     NA 
 4 bar   rab   NA       NA       0.75     1.5
```

**NOTE**: This is based on my example. The full df, will contain all four conditions (`A,B,C,D`) and thus no `NA` values are expected.

The latter obviously does not work. If I want to avoid a loop that nests the summarise operation, how would I go about this?

Comment: It is because the `length` are not the same after the subset.   Can you show your expected output

Comment: @akrun thank you for the valuable input. Expected output added. I tried with `%in%` using the real df that has entries for each of the values in `cond3` (A,B,C,D) and can be grouped for all conditions on the selected columns (`cond1` and `cond2`) but this returns `Error: Column `ratios` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 4`. Which I believe indicates to explicitly assign the ratios one by one.

Comment: So you want to divide the corresponding elements of each list?  The expected 'AB', 'AD', 'CB', 'CD' or is it all pairs?

Comment: Why don't you use map2_df after group_split?

Comment: @akrun Correct. Added the explicit version of the summarise operation, which I would like to make dynamic, as I do not know the contents of the lists (`list1` and `list2`) in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a combinations datasets from 'list1', 'list2' with `crossing`, use `pmap` to loop over the rows, do the grouping  on the original dataset 'df' by 'cond1', 'cond2', `summarise` by creating the 'ratio_' column after subsetting the 'value' based on the combination dataset on the 'cond3' and `reduce` them to a single dataset with `full_join`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
crossing(list1, list2) %>%
   pmap(~ df %>% 
            group_by(cond1, cond2) %>%
            summarise(!! str_c('ratio_', ..1, ..2) :=
                 value[cond3 == ..1]/value[cond3 == ..2], .groups = 'drop')) %>% 
   reduce(full_join, by = c('cond1', 'cond2'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
#  cond1 cond2 ratio_AB ratio_AD ratio_CB ratio_CD
#  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 buz   oof      0.667   NA        0.333     NA  
#2 foo   bar      0.5      0.25     2          1  
#3 foo   oof      0.5      0.333   NA         NA  
#4 bar   rab     NA       NA        0.75       1.5
```

The `!!` on the lhs of assignment operator is to evaluate the string created with `str_c` to be assigned as the column name.  Usually, when we do the assignment with `=`, the lhs will be unquoted column name and in `base R`, we use `setNames` with `paste` to make new column names

Comment: Seems interesting to learn.  Can you please explain `!!` and := Upvoted.

Comment: This a nice solution and learned some syntactic sugar here! Thank you!

Comment: @AnilGoyal added some explanations. Hope it helps thanks

Comment: @akrun Sorry to catch up on this once more. What needs to be added in case of missing columns for some of the groups, e.g. one of the values in list1 or list2 is not present after grouping sp that summarise cannot be done. I receive an Error: `Column ratio_AB must be length 1 (a summary value), not 0`

Comment: @Fourier can you post as a new question.  thanks

Comment: @akrun I feel it is too similar, should I update the existing one?

Comment: @Fourier It is almost  6 months back and some of the things may have changed